# "was" vs "has been"

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

There is the sentence "The group was upgraded to a super-group", and it's weird because the message will be showed for me when I decide to upgrade my conference to super-group:

I've clicked on "Upgrade" and the conference is upgraded and after this I see the message the conference has been/was upgraded. That's why I don't understand why there is "was upgraded" instead of "has been upgraded". Explain me that, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has/have been vs was/were](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273230/has-have-been-vs-was-were)

Comment: Note that "explain me that" is ungrammatical.

Comment: [will be shown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you find the sentence "weird".  The action happened and it is complete, so the simple past is perfectly acceptable.

> I just got out of a meeting with the city planning commission where I **was given** approval for my construction project.

In this case the *approval* is a single, discrete action.  There is no need for the present perfect which often implies *continuous* or *repeated* actions that continue up to the present moment.

In the case of your example, it's a difference that makes little difference:

> The group **was** upgraded.  (*Upgrading* is a **discrete action** that is complete)
>
> The group **has been** upgraded (*Upgrading* is an **ongoing process** that is now complete).

The use of "was" vs. "has been" simply reflects the *opinion* of the designer, whether that person thinks of the upgrade as a single, short event, or as a process that takes time.

Side note: The writers of an application should make sure all of this kind of messaging is *consistent* -- they shouldn't use "was" in some cases and "has been" in others.  This consistency helps the end user feel the application is *stable* and *reliable* -- that it will always return consistent results.

Comment: For example: if a player is cheating in a game and an administrator decide to ban him, the violator gets ban and he instantly gets the message "You have been banned from the server". Why not "was" but "have been"?

Comment: "has been" is used to introduce news, like in your example "you have been banned" and is more common in British English, whereas "was" is more common in American English.